# What is the difference between $\propto$ and $\sim$

Tags: soft-question, definition

Suppose I have two physical quantities, lets name them $a$ and $b$.

I wonder what the difference exactly is between 
$$a\propto b,\tag{1}$$
and
$$a \sim b.\tag{2}$$

I know for eq. 1, that it means $a=kb$. (See e.g. [What does the sign $\propto$ mean?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/652207/what-does-the-sign-propto-mean))

For eq. 2 I found [Meaning of $\sim$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/858917/meaning-of-sim) , but it is applied to functions, e.g.$ \lim_{x \rightarrow x_0} \frac{a(x)}{b(x)} = 1 $, but I am a bit confused on what it means in the context of plain physical quantities. Same order of magnitude? Does it imply a linear scaling as $\propto$?

Comment: Can you say more about the context? Most symbols do not have a single meaning. For example, your second symbol could mean "equivalent to", "asymptotic to", or something situationally defined.

Comment: The first usually means "[proportional to](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proportionality_%28mathematics%29#Symbols)".

Comment: @Marc I have a balance equation (momentum). Basically, I keep the largest terms on both sides. They are not equal anymore, and I think $\approx$ does not feel right, but I want to indicate that they more or less scale in the same way. I am wondering if $\sim$ would be appropriate. Someone told me $\propto$ and $\sim$ mean the same thing. But I am not convinced.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Thanks, I have the wiki-page open already :). For the first one I am quite certain, my doubt is mainly in the second one.

Comment: If you are just keeping the largest terms, it sounds like you are in an asymptotic situation. Is there a limit being taken?

Comment: I have seen sometimes $\sim$ used as "proportional to", but actually, $\sim$ may mean many things depending on context. In *maths* it's mainly what you have written, but it's also used in probability to say "variable X follow the distribution D", or in group theory to mean two groups are isomorphic (not sure this one is standard, I have also seen $\simeq$).

Comment: @Marc Formally that is what I am doing, although the limit is implicitly taken (i.e. based on physical grounds).

Comment: I think the answer is that $a \sim b$ means the same thing as $a \propto b,$ except when it doesn't.

Comment: "More or less scale in the same way" - with respect to changing what variable?  Then the two sides are being treated as functions of that variable so the "asymptotic" interpretation would make sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Like you said,  $a \propto b$ means: **a is proportional to b** and so:

$a \propto b\Rightarrow a=k\cdot b$ for some $k \in \mathbb{R}$

2. In contrast: $a \sim b$ means: **a is distributed according to b** and so:

$a \sim b \Rightarrow \lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} \dfrac{a(x)}{b(x)} = 1 $

So, $\sim$ indicates identical asymptotic behavior for arbitrary functions $a,b$. Maybe functions over time for your usecase?
Note that although $a \propto b$ is a more general statement than $a \sim b$ since it holds for all values of $a$ and $b$, rather than only for the limit, it does not imply $a \sim b$.